# Laptop refusing to boot from USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi, surface

### Hello and thank you for taking your time to read about my problem!

About the device I use:

- Microsoft Surface Laptop
- Windows 11 Home, 22H2
- i5-11300H
- 16 GB RAM
- 64-Bit OS

### My Problem:

I wanted to have a dualboot on my laptop and tried to install Ubuntu 22.04 using a USB, it worked perfectly fine till I tried to install a [Linux-surface Kernel](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup). After installing `secureboot-mok` I restarted my laptop and got stuck on bootscreen. Since then I was not able to boot the ubuntu installation nor start a new ubunutu installation via the USB.

### What I have tried:

- I have tried using a different USB
  -> not changing anything.
- I have tried this USB on two differenc Lenovo-Thinpad devices and it worked perfectly fine.
- I have checked if the Laptop is able to read a different bootable-USB and yes it is able to start a "Windows-USB".
- I have tried disabling secureboot
- I have tried to force my device to boot the stick by holding the lower-volume button and pressing power button-> Just stuck on bootscreen.
- I have tried to boot the USB via the UEFI. -> Just stuck on bootscreen.
- I have tried to reset the Laptop to the state before the first installation using a system image I created beforehand. -> no result

### I am out of ideas

I have tried multiple ways of booting the USB without any result. The USB seems fine ( since it worked on different devices ). The laptop seems fine ( since it reckognized a different USB and was able to boot from it ).

I am happy about any advice or suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What tool did you use to create USB live installer? Is it in UEFI boot mode, some tools create either UEFI or BIOS only create an installer in one mode. Newer systems are UEFI only, so you have to boot in UEFI mode. You may need to turn off UEFI secure boot or change other settings in UEFI to allow USB boot. Better Support For Microsoft Surface Laptops On Linux Is Coming With "SAM" Dec 2020
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Microsoft-Surface-SAM-Linux
Surface Pro Ubuntu install:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365819

Comment: Some systems have builtin proprietary blocks against changing the OS configuration. You'll likely need to google your make/model specifically. Look at your BIOS options. The answer will be there. +1 for SecureBoot,

Comment: @oldfred I used balenaEtcher because it was recommended on the [Ubuntu-website](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#3-create-a-bootable-usb-stick). BalenaEtcher doesnt give me a lot of information about how and in which way they do it. Same goes for the Surface-UEFI, there is very little room for adjustments.

Comment: @oldfred furthermore I have tried using Rufus to create the live USB to try both partition schemes (GPT and MBR), neither worked. And I have tried both ISO-Image-Mode and DD-Image-Mode.

Comment: Only use gpt, The only place for MBR is for BIOS only systems prior to 2012 with Windows BIOS install. +1 on searching for your specific model. The links above all all the info I have on Surface. Many laptops have special keys to open up more UEFI settings, check manual or have to have UEFI Secure boot on to have more settings. I would not plan on using a Microsoft product with Linux, although Microsoft is not as bad as it was in DOS days where court records years later showed they would not release software that installed on competing DOS.